# Unknown error while retrieving django queryset objects from redis

Tags: python, django, django-models, redis

In the below code snippet, I am trying to bring the cached objects from redis , while doing it facing the below error.

The use case is caching the top 30 comment objects at the 1st API call , so the when the API is called for 2 nd time, the cached objects will be passed to serialzers , avoiding the querysets.

Caching the comments objects.

```
featured=StockUserComments.objects.filter(some condition)
qs=StockUserComments.objects.filter(some condition)
latest=StockUserComments.objects.filter(some condition)

all =list(chain(featured,qs,latest))

redis_client.set("feeds:top_comments", str(all[:30]),ex=1800)
```

retrieving the objects

```
top_comments = redis_client.get("feeds:top_comments")
if top_comments:
  print("from cache")
  all = ast.literal_eval(top_comments.decode("utf-8"))
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\apps\stock_dashboard\views.py", line 748, in get
    all = ast.literal_eval(top_comments.decode("utf-8"))
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [<StockUserComments: Cm>, <StockUserComments: R3>, <StockUserComments: Re>, <StockUserComments: N5>, <StockUserComments: New1>, <StockUserComments: R1>, <StockUserComments: Cm>, <StockU
serComments: New2>, <StockUserComments: ~EMPTY_COMMENT>, <StockUserComments: ~EMPTY_COMMENT>, <StockUserComments: I think it’s time to sell here>, <StockUserComments: ~EMPTY_COMMENT>, <Stoc
kUserComments: ~EMPTY_COMMENT>, <StockUserComments: ~EMPTY_COMMENT>, <StockUserComments: Time to sell indeed>, <StockUserComments: Time to sell.￼￼>, <StockUserComments: What a great company
 huge opportunities ahead. I would definitely be a buyer here. Although this is a risky one lots of volatility be careful
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You don't have to use `ast.literal_eval`. Did you serialize your objects in `redis_client`?

Comment: no just the objects were sent to redis

Comment: Try to see what type of output you have without `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: it has just numbers with out ast.literal_val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to serialize your objects (aside from using `str` and `ast.literal_eval`, which actually will not work), is to use `pickle`:

```
import pickle
redis_client.set("feeds:top_comments", pickle.dumps(all[:30]), ex=1800)
```

This will serialize your queryset as bytes which can be retrieved back as queryset. You can then retrieve with:

```
import pickle
top_comments = redis_client.get("feeds:top_comments")
all = pickle.loads(top_comments)
```

Note that the queryset you get from `pickle.loads` can be outdated compared to what you have in the database. In that case, you can serialize using the object ids instead and just fetch them again. Note that you can also use other kinds of serialization like json if you want.